# Installing Rocketchat server on Raspbian with Snap

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, raspbian-lite, raspbian-buster

I'm trying to install Rocketchat on my Raspberry pi by following [these instructions](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.RaspberryPi)
When trying to install rocketchat-server using Snap I get the following error:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "rocketchat-server" snap if present (run hook "configure": "((enable)|(disable))" is not a valid, set to enable or disable)
```

I have searched thoroughly, trying several search terms, but I can't find any results with the same or a similar error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instruction is for Raspberry Pi 4 or later hardware only.

The Rocket.Chat server has grown in size and hardware requirement; you will need a board with 2GB of RAM or more.

We have tested the procedure with the latest available release of Raspbian; and many in [our community](https://open.rocket.chat/channel/raspberrypi) have had success installing the server via snap.  If you are using an older board or an older version of Raspbian, the error you reported is a possible showstopper.

Please make sure you are following [the instructions](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.RaspberryPi/blob/master/README.md) precisely, and you have:

1. Raspberry Pi 4 - 2GB or 4GB RAM
2. The latest available [Raspbian Buster Lite for Pi 4](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).
3. Installed **snapd** as per instructions

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a link; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed or you risk to get down votes. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: I see... I was trying to install it on my Raspberry Pi 3. I'll try again when I get a Raspberry Pi 4, thanks for the answer.